# Objective-C: Аудиоплеер

Tags: ios, objective-c, аудио

Есть TableViewController с названиями аудио файлов и ViewController с проигрывателем. Если пользователь нажимает на строчку в TableViewController то попадает в ViewController где аудио начинает играть.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы после окончания одного аудио приложение начинало проигрывать следующее.

Как лучше это сделать? Можно в ViewController после окончания аудио возвращаться в TableViewController и оттуда переходить к следующему треку? Или есть более лучший способ перейти к следующему треку?

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AudioPlayer.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) AudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPVolumeView *volumeView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* _paintView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *currentTimeSlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *duration;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeElapsed;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@property BOOL isPaused;
@property BOOL scrubbing;

@property NSTimer *timer;

@property (readwrite) NSInteger index;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

if (_index == 0) {
    self.audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
    [self setupAudioPlayer:@"1"];
        _timeElapsed.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"time0"];
        _currentTimeSlider.value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"time 0"];
        [self setCurrentTime:self];
}
    else if (_index == 1) {
    self.audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
    [self setupAudioPlayer:@"2"];
        _timeElapsed.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"time1"];
        _currentTimeSlider.value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"time 1"];
        [self setCurrentTime:self];
}
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}

- (void)setupAudioPlayer:(NSString*)fileName
{

    NSString *fileExtension = @"mp3";

    [self.audioPlayer initPlayer:fileName fileExtension:fileExtension];
    self.currentTimeSlider.maximumValue = [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration];

    self.timeElapsed.text = @"0:00";

    self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",
                          [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration]]];

    [self playAudioPressed:_playButton];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
}

- (IBAction)playAudioPressed:(id)playButton
{


    [self.timer invalidate];
    if (!self.isPaused) {
        [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"]
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];

        [self.audioPlayer playAudio];
        self.isPaused = TRUE;

    } else {
        [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"]
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
        self.isPaused = FALSE;
    }
}

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {


    if (!self.scrubbing) {
        self.currentTimeSlider.value = [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime];
    }
    self.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                             [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

    self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",
                          [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration] - [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

    if (![self.audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"]
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
        self.isPaused = FALSE;

    }
    if (self.isPaused == TRUE) {
        if (_index == 0) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_duration.text forKey:@"timeImage0"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_timeElapsed.text forKey:@"time0"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:_currentTimeSlider.value forKey:@"time 0"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        else if (_index == 1) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_duration.text forKey:@"timeImage1"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_timeElapsed.text forKey:@"time1"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:_currentTimeSlider.value forKey:@"time 1"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_duration.text forKey:@"time 167"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
}

- (IBAction)setCurrentTime:(id)scrubber {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

    [self.audioPlayer setCurrentAudioTime:self.currentTimeSlider.value];
    self.scrubbing = FALSE;
}
```

**AudioPlayer.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AudioPlayer : UIViewController  <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (readwrite) NSInteger index;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property UIButton * btnaudio;

- (void)initPlayer:(NSString*) audioFile fileExtension:(NSString*)fileExtension;
- (void)playAudio;
- (void)pauseAudio;
- (BOOL)isPlaying;
- (void)setCurrentAudioTime:(float)value;
- (float)getAudioDuration;
- (NSString*)timeFormat:(float)value;
- (NSTimeInterval)getCurrentAudioTime;

@end
```

**AudioPlayer.m**

```
#import "AudioPlayer.h"
@implementation AudioPlayer

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
}

- (void) song{

   if (_index == 0) { 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.mp3"];
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:nil];
    }
    else if (_index == 1) {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.mp3"];
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:nil];
    }
}
- (void)initPlayer:(NSString*) audioFile fileExtension:(NSString*)fileExtension
{

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:audioFile withExtension:fileExtension];
    NSError *error;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];

    if ([audioFile isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        _index = 0;
    }
    else if ([audioFile isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        _index = 1;
    }
    [self song];
    }
- (void)playAudio {
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}

- (void)pauseAudio {
    [self.audioPlayer pause];

}
- (BOOL)isPlaying {
    return [self.audioPlayer isPlaying];
}
-(NSString*)timeFormat:(float)value{

    float minutes = floor(lroundf(value)/60);
    float seconds = lroundf(value) - (minutes * 60);

    int roundedSeconds = lroundf(seconds);
    int roundedMinutes = lroundf(minutes);

    NSString *time = [[NSString alloc]
                      initWithFormat:@"%d:%02d",
                      roundedMinutes, roundedSeconds];

    return time;
}

- (void)setCurrentAudioTime:(float)value {
    [self.audioPlayer setCurrentTime:value];
}
- (NSTimeInterval)getCurrentAudioTime {
    return [self.audioPlayer currentTime];
}
- (float)getAudioDuration {
    return [self.audioPlayer duration];
}

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");
}
```

Comment: передать массивом все треки, создать плеер со всеми сразу и начать играть с нужного

Comment: Каким компонентом играешь аудио?

Comment: Добавил код. Как после окончания 1 файла  добавить воспроизведение  2?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Мне нужно именно после окончания аудио переходить из ViewController (с первым треком) в TableViewController и оттуда переходить в ViewController (со вторым треком) автоматически т.к под каждый трек есть своя информация в ViewController. Как это можно сделать в коде? Что-то не получается…

Comment: что именно не получается?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko после окончание игры вернуться в TableViewController. Как вообще понять что файл закончил проигрывание?

Comment: что это за AudioPlayer? это AVAudioPlayer или что то другое?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko это AVAudioPlayer

Comment: у него в делегате есть метод didFinishPlaying https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayerdelegate/1389160-audioplayerdidfinishplaying

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Добавил, но почему-то не вызывается

Comment: делегатом себя объявить не забыли?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko в .h добавил  <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> в .m  self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;

Comment: покажите весь код

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Добавил полный код. AudioPlayer - плеер ViewController - контроллер с плеером

Comment: вы сначала создаете плеер во viewDidLoad, и потом вызываете метод initPlayer:fileExtension, который создает новый плеер и уже у него делегата нету.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Все работает. А как теперь начать проигрывать следующий трек?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо добавить `DataSource` в `ViewController`

```
@protocol AudioPlayerDataSource <NSObject>

- (nullable NSString *)audioFileNameForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

При клике на ячейку передавать в контроллер индекс ячейки

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    controller.dataSource = self;
    controller.currentIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controlleranimated:YES];
}
```

когда одно аудио проигралось до конца, спрашиваете у `dataSource` название файла для следующего индекса. Если пришел `nil`, значит вы дошли до конца списка.